# It could be disturbing

Tags: rebus

The following rebus is one that should be very familiar to a great number of people, but may require an unexpected thought process.

> $(\huge ma$$)\ \epsilon \ 1$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \wedge$

---

$\small \color{red}{Note: Mathjax\ displays\ differently,\ per\ computer\ resolution,\ so\ here\ is}$
$\small \color{red}{what\ the\ question\ should\ look\ like\ if\ you're\ having\ trouble.}$

[image: Picture with arrow correctly pointing at the 1.]

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/kxdmrk5fl/ Solvable or no? If not please provide a picture of the desktop version

Comment: @warspyking looks like it does on my desktop

Comment: @Jonathan Allan Awesome :D

Comment: Aww... I was hoping this was a Rogue Squadron puzzle.

Comment: :) @LeppyR64 hehe

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I went ahead and kept the puzzle with your screenshot, despite it removing one of the clues, because Mathjax is apparently stupid and displays differently, per resolution, so I can't make the puzzle actually look the same for everyone.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha "despite it removing one of the clues" Hmm, which one? I tried to put the original code of you in `<!--` `-->` blocks, but that didn't really worked.. Also, you could perhaps display both your original one and the image (with an explanation that people are having different resolutions and the `^` is supposed to point to the `1`).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good idea (And the comment referred to the part of the puzzle that was removed, so was a bit out-of-context without it.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> The force is strong with this one.
>  - Darth Vader

Force = mass * acceleration (ma)

The (ma) is really big and strong.

The epsilon is for sets.  The (ma) is with the 1.

The 1 is "one" and the arrow (or wedge) is pointing to "this one".

Interesting note:
In the edit text the up arrow is called a wedge.  The OP has a hidden comment in the text that says:

> No, Biggs and Wedge aren't part of this.  Quit looking at the edit screen.

It's a reference to two of the pilots that flew with Luke in Red Squadron.

Rogue Squadron was a group formed by Luke for doing other missions.

The Rogue Squadron book series that came out in the 90's.  Now I have my summer reading set of me.

Comment: I thought that, but the epsilon??

Comment: Yeah I can't explain it yet either :)

Comment: The title of the riddle definitely fits this answer. "I sense a disturbance in the Force" and "I find you lack of faith disturbing".

Comment: Maybe OP meant to use \in rather than \epsilon? Wait, that's still not a with...

Comment: @ffao I doubt it.

Comment: I think this must be right; perhaps the OP misremembered the quotation as "... in this one". (The set-membership symbol was actually originally an epsilon, short for "is" in Latin, Greek, etc.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I find your lack of faith (in OP) disturbing ;)

Comment: Haha, actually I was going to allow either one.  I was using the epsilon to refer to "is" as in set, or "with" as in "within".  Btw, LeppyR64, I think you were the only one that caught the hidden clue.

Comment: any explanation?

Comment: @Mr_Green Updated

Answer (score 5):

How about

> "This little one's not worth the effort" (Obe-Wan Kenobi)?

Since

> The arrow, this, points to the one, epsilon means a small quantity, a range in parentheses does not include the endpoints, $F=ma$ force is effort.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about this, but is it:

> Force multiplier? ma could stand for mass x acceleration which is the equation for force. The arrow is pointing at the space between the epsilon and the 1 which in mathematics implicitly indicates a multiply operation.

Comment: The arrow is intending to point *at* the 1.  The syntax didn't allow further design precision.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. You might want to note that in the question.